# Why a single byte corruption while manipulating with plain text files could happen?

Tags: python, file, byte, text-files, corruption

I am really confused here, and I even cannot state the topic of the question more clearly. While manipulating with the plain text files I encountered a weird replacement of symbols (bytes).

For example, I had a file with about 20000 strings, one of which is:
MIEPTLIRVGEAFYDITHLAPTRHTVPVLVRGNFAKVPVRISYTNHCYSRTPRAGEQVPTGHEIKDGAKLRMFCEQRHRLSSYLPQILIDLLQGETSLWQAAGGNFLQVELVDDVDGEPPTKIEYNVILRMERLKPEGDQKHIMIRVETAYPEDIEYDKPFRKKS**Y**KVSRILAAKWEDRDHREPEPKPGKGKGKAKKK

I merge about 1000 of such files together just writing them one after another with Python (using simple open(filename) method). In the resulting file in the corresponding string I saw (while all other strings are fine):
MIEPTLIRVGEAFYDITHLAPTRHTVPVLVRGNFAKVPVRISYTNHCYSRTPRAGEQVPTGHEIKDGAKLRMFCEQRHRLSSYLPQILIDLLQGETSLWQAAGGNFLQVELVDDVDGEPPTKIEYNVILRMERLKPEGDQKHIMIRVETAYPEDIEYDKPFRKKS**Щ**KVSRILAAKWEDRDHREPEPKPGKGKGKAKKK

Thus, a replacement of "Y" (HEX 59) to "Щ" letter (HEX D9) happened (both letters are made bold above). If I do this procedure again, no replacement occur in this place, thus it is random (?). I also noticed the same kind of replacement happening with "P" (HEX 50) and russian "Р" letter (HEX D0) in other case. What unites these cases is that in both cases letters in a pair have the same number if we count from 0 and 128 position of the ASCII table: english P has position 80, and russian Р has position 128+80=208; letter Y has position 89 and letter "Щ" has position 128+89=217. I guess this is a kind of file corruption, but how and why does it happen? Any ideas?

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  Asking us to speculate on a flipped bit in an unspecified process ... is off-topic here.

Comment: While it's theoretically possible for a computer to make a random error like this, it's extremely unlikely. Unless there's a hardware problem with your PC, you should never encounter it, certainly not multiple times.

Comment: using `open(filename)` you open in text mode which can convert some chars - like new line which may have different code on different systems. It may try to read it as `utf-8` but you may have files in different encodings. If you want only concatenate file then better do it in bytes-mode `open(filename, "rb")` - but it can't help you if you have files in different encodings. Text files normally don't have information what encoding was used and you have to guess.

Comment: Prune, I'm sorry but the specific dataset would not help because - as I wrote - it happens non-frequently (in a file of around 3Gb size I noticed two such flips). I spent a couple of hours trying to figure out WHAT does happen here and if this is a Python problem or a filesystem error or something else...

Comment: Barmar, I guess this could be an issue because I converted a file while working on non-new removable drive - so it possibly could have been a hardware failure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have guessed it myself before even asking: actually it looks like a single bit flip which likely could occur randomly as an error of reading/writing to disk. If the very first bit in a byte coding a letter flips, the replacement becomes visible because the letter is no longer in the first 128 symbols of ASCII table and some software becomes cranky about it.

```
"Y" = 01011001
"Щ" = 11011001 

"P" = 01010000 
"Р" = 11010000
```